# Running mysql query if column is false in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display results of a mysql query and some html if the first mysql queries coulmn returns false or is set to false. I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get it to work properly, I will show code below. Any help is much appreciated. In the code I want to only display site message if the user's acknowledgement is false otherwise don't display anything.

```
function siteWideMessage()                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                          
    global $dbh;                                                                                                           



$siteMessage = "";                                                                                                     

$sUserInfo = $dbh->prepare("                                                                                           
    SELECT acknowledgement                                                                                             
    FROM user                                                                                                          
    WHERE uid = :uid                                                                                                   
");                                                                                                                    
$sUserInfo->bindValue(":uid", $_SESSION["uid"]);                                                                       
if ($sUserInfo->execute()) {                                                                                           
    $res = $sUserInfo->fetch();                                                                                        
    if ($res["acknowledgement"] = false) {                                                                             
        $stmt = $dbh->query("                                                                                          
            SELECT message                                                                                             
            FROM SiteWideMessages                                                                                      
            ORDER BY idSiteWideMessages DESC                                                                           
            LIMIT 1                                                                                                    
        ");                                                                                                            
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {                                                                                
            $siteMessage .= "                                                                                          
                <div class='siteMessage'>                                                                              
                    <span>" . $row["message"] . "</span>                                                               
                    <br><br>                                                                                           
                    <span style='font-weight:normal;'>I acknowledge that I have read this important site message</span>
                    <br>                                                                                               
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='I Agree'></input>                                        
            </div>";                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                  
    $sUserInfo->closeCursor();                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                      

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {                                                                                         

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("                                                                                            
        UPDATE user                                                                                                    
        SET `acknowledgement` = 'true'                                                                                 
        WHERE uid = :uid                                                                                               
    ");                                                                                                                
    $stmt->bindValue(":uid", $_SESSION["uid"]);                                                                        
    if($stmt->execute()) {                                                                                             
        $stmt->closeCursor();                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                      
return $siteMessage;                                                                                                 }
```

UPDATE:
I managed to get it working the way I want it to I just had to do as the following.

```
if ($res["acknowledgement"] == 'false')
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: if($res["acknowledgement"] = false) is not a check, you set it to false and the IF will always fail.. add 1 more =

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply Svetlio, I think I must have a bigger underlining problem or maybe my logic is wrong. I'm trying to use if($res["acknowledgement"] == false) which I was thinking it would display results if that column(acknowledgement) in mysql is false. Am I correct or is my logic wrong?

Comment: Actually I think I got it, I used if($res["acknowledgement"] == 'false') and it's display properly. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `=` in your if statement. It should be:

```
...
if ($res["acknowledgement"] === false) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jerodev, I managed to get the logic to work properly I just had to use '==' and turn the false into a string. It's displaying properly now.